# Resolving a class name conflict in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conflict, classname, ruport

I have been building a Rails application that performs accounting functionality. As part of this, I have a model with the class name `Transaction`. So far so good, I have been building this functionality for a month or so, and everything is working as expected.

Until now...

I have just discovered some older reporting functionality that was developed months ago using the Ruport library has stopped working. It appears that Ruport, when generating PDFs, requires a library that also has a class/module named `Transaction`.

```
TypeError in Admin/team reportsController#generate
Transaction is not a module

...

This error occurred while loading the following files:
  pdf/writer
  transaction/simple
```

So, I'm looking for a quick fix here. One that hopefully doesn't involve renaming my `Transaction` model and refactoring the last few weeks worth of code.

Looking forward to some clever suggestions :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the issue is down to Ruport requiring the PDF::Writer gem, which in turn requires the Transaction::Simple gem which defines the module Transaction.

There is certainly a #transaction method in ActiveRecord, but I do not think there is a Transaction module or class within Rails. I'll be happy to be corrected on that one.

Namespacing is usually the best practice for avoiding naming conflicts like this. E.g.

```
module Account
  class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
  end
end
```

However, namespacing ActiveRecord models may throw up other issues.

As time consuming as it may be, renaming your Transaction model may be the best bet.

You can still keep your existing transactions database table if you wanted, so your migrations don't need to change, by putting `self.table_name = "transactions"` inside your model.

Your associations with other models can also still be named "transaction(s)" by specifying the class_name in your association call. E.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "AccountTransaction"

end
```

Those two suggestions may or may not save you some time.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed your answer to the accepted answer as it more accurately describes the specific problem I have - although Yannis, answer is also correct! In the end I resorted to renaming my model, database table, and all associations using some old-skool find and replace ;)

Comment: In the newer version of Rails, `set_table_name` is just `self.table_name =`, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D

Answer (score 15):

Already answered and old, but I came here with the same problem, but solved it in a different way.

I have two Models named Pull and Query.
Trying to reference `Query.some_static_method()` within a method in Pull resulted in Query resolving to `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query:Module`.

Solved it by putting the empty namespace in front of it with `::Query.some_static_method()`

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know about the empty namespace!

Comment: Elegant solution.  Could you explain exactly why/how it works?

Comment: @cph2117, all that really does is be explicit about which namespace is to find `Query`.

Comment: Man, you deserve a medal

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may come from the fact that Transaction is also a reserved word in Rails…

Comment: Rails is just a Ruby library, it cannot add any keywords to the Ruby language.

Comment: It might just be a library, but it can impose limits on the naming of things using it (even though these are of cause not enforced by the language). Just look at the trouble you get in when trying to use the column name 'type' ...